# Drush-error when using field-create

Tags: drush

Trying to make a field with Drush, i get the following error

First, the version

```
root@homer:/usr/share/nginx/html/8/sites/default# drush version
 Drush Version   :  8.0.1
```

Try to make a field 'voorvoegsel' (dutch) with field-create in Content-type contact

```
root@homer:/usr/share/nginx/html/8/sites/default# drush field-create contact voorvoegsel,text
PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function field_info_field() in phar:///usr/local/bin/drush/commands/core/field.drush.inc on line 175
Drush command terminated abnormally due to an unrecoverable error.                                                                                                    [error]
Error: Call to undefined function field_info_field() in phar:///usr/local/bin/drush/commands/core/field.drush.inc, line 175
```

Googling gives me no clue, so i post this here. Can't find a (good) solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Drush doesn't support field commands for Drupal 8 yet. The error message is caused by the fact that Drupal 8 no longer has a function field_info_field() - see Drupal change record at https://www.drupal.org/node/2260037

Drush issue at https://github.com/drush-ops/drush/issues/230

Comment: Thanks, wasn't aware of that. Is indeed Dr8, not 7.

Comment: This is still not working.